# UI sortable for Select Item in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-bootstrap, angularjs-ng-model, angular-ui-select

Below is my code,which I have tried

UI-sortable option is not working in this line

```
  <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="i.items as i.items for i in curItem" ui-sortable="sortableOptions"ng-init="selectedItem=curItem[0].items"></select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ui-sortable library should import in the top of the application Controller.